# Сортировка потомков для определенного родителя

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется некоторый каталог товара, пользователь далжен уметь добавлять товар и соответствующую ему категорию в корзину и производить сортировку как между категориями так и между товарами внутри категории.
Есть таблица "Категории"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category] (
    [Id]   INT          IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

есть таблица "Товар"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product] (
    [Id]        INT          IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Id_category] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]      VARCHAR (50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([Id_category]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([Id])
);
```

и есть еще две таблицы "Пользователь" и "Корзина"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Id]        INT          IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Login]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      VARCHAR (50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Last_Name] VARCHAR (50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_Login_Pass] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Login] ASC, [Password] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cart] (
    [Id]         INT IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Id_user]    INT NOT NULL,
    [Id_category]  INT NOT NULL,
    [Index_sort] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_User_Category] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id_user] ASC, [Id_category] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_User_Sort] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id_user] ASC, [Index_sort] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Cart_User] FOREIGN KEY ([Id_user]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Cart_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([Id_category]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id])
);
```

Сортировку по категории выполнил в таблице корзина. Как сделать пользовательскую сортировку товара внутри категории?

Только знакомлюсь с БД. Пробовал следующим образом:
добивил таблицу "Сортировка товара"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product_sort] (
    [Id_cart] INT NOT NULL,
    [Id_product]     INT NOT NULL,
    [Index_sort]     INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UK_Cart_Sort] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id_cart] ASC, [Index_sort] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UK_Cart_Id_Product] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Id_cart] ASC, [Id_product] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([Id_cart]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cart] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_sort_Cart] FOREIGN KEY ([Id_product]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([Id])
);
```

но здесь появилась проблема в таблице сортировка товара можно указать товар для категории в которой его на самом деле нет. Подскажите как решить проблему.

Comment: Я бы не парился и контролировал на уровне приложения. У вас все равно появляется куча неоднозначностей. предположим вы как то зафиксируете категорию в product_sort, отсортируете внутри нее. а товар перенесут в другую категорию и либо вам придется проходить все корзины и менять категории и еще принимать решение о новом порядке сортировки, который пользователь не делал. т.е. выходит что без вмешательства пользователя проблема вообще не решается.

Comment: P.S. Если это действительно категории, то обычно у товара может быть несколько категорий ...